# Can you override private methods in a trait in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have a trait:

```
trait Thing[B, A <: OtherThing[B]] { 
  ...
  private def SomeMethod() =
    s"someString"
```

and some object that extends this trait:

```
object ImplementingThing extends Thing[SomeThing1, Something2] {
    ...
    override def SomeMethod() =
      s"SomeOtherFilePathString"
```

Is this possible? Or do I have to make the trait's private method public? If this can't be done, what's the reason behind this?

Also, quick unrelated question (I know, I know, but it saves me a post), what is the relationship between A and B as defined by the trait?

Comment: Scala follows the same OOPs concepts as Java so we can not override private method of super class/trait because it is not visible outside the class/trait.

Comment: You can make the method `protected` which will leave it visible to subclasses of `Thing` but private to all other objects.

Comment: I do not know Java

Answer (score 3):

Private methods are invisible to both implementors and outside classes. As such, no, you cannot override a private method. For the same reasons, you also cannot have an abstract private method.

```
@ trait Lol {
    private val a: Int
  }

cmd0.sc:2: abstract member may not have private modifier
  private val a: Int
              ^
Compilation Failed
```

Protected methods, on the other hand, are visible to implementors but not to outside classes. Protected methods can be overridden.